# sql query to get sum of two columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. I want to add all the values of one column from table 1 to all the values of a particular column of table 2. How to do that?

for example

table A

```
Id Name  Salary 
1    A   20000 
2    B   30000
```

table B

```
Id Name   Salary 
1    A    30000 
2    B    40000
```

I want the result as `total salary= sum(salary of table A) + sum(salary of table B)`

Here result should come as 120000

Answer (score 1):

Do this with a subquery:

```
select a.s + b.s
from (select sum(salary) as s from a) cross join
     (select sum(salary) as s from b);
```

Or, if one of the tables could be empty, `union all` would be better:

```
select sum(salary)
from (select id, name, salary from a union all
      select id, name, salary from b
     ) ab;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a Union first. Try this query:

```
select sum(salary) from 
(
select sum(Salary) as salary from tableA
union 
select sum(Salary) as salary from tableB
)
```

Comment: If both the tables have the same sum of salary this will report half the correct amount.